# Unable to exit an Application

Tags: android, android-activity

The objective is to kill the alarm application when the Dismiss button is pressed.
However, I am unable to do so.

In order to kill the application, I tried using `finish()` and `finishAffinity()` , also tried the lethal way as well :D

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

And in the end, all of em succeeds closing the application. But
[image]

Pressing the Square button at the right bottom, re-opens the closed application. Is there an effective solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [android:excludefromrecents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude) flag on your alarm activity, and it will not show up on the Recent Tasks screen (but this is even *before* they dismiss the alarm!).

Don't use killProcess(). In the Android app model, you should let the system handle processes.